# How to check for user's role on another server?

Tags: discord.py

Have a function checking a role on a specific server, but the function is supposed to be sent by a pm to the bot, so I can't use "role code" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]
What should I do?

Also need to send a message to the specific server

Function in question:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if '%attented' in message.content:
        if "561055432748302336" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            msg = message.content.split(' ')
            author = message.author
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560679934209687552'), str(author) + ' has attented a ' + msg[2] + '\nScreenshot:' + msg[1] + '/n***To approve screenshot react with :HYPERS: to dissaprove react with :FeelsBadMan:***')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these two methods for that

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for i in bot.servers:
        for x in i.roles:
            if x.id == 'the role id': #this can also be done through name via x.name == 'name'
                await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='channel id'), 'the message')
    await bot.process_commands(msg)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def role(msg):
    for i in bot.servers:
        for x in i.roles:
            if x.id == ' the role id': #you can also do this by name via x.name
                await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='channel id here'), "The message to send")

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(emote,user):
    if emote.emoji == '':
        #Do something here
        await bot.send_message(emote.message.channel,f"{user.name} has reacted")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def get_message(msg):
    async for i in bot.logs_from(msg.message.channel):
        if i.author.id == '185181025104560128' and 'hello' in i.content:
            print(i.content)
```

You can't get the users that reacted to the messages with a regular command function in `async` and can only be done in `rewrite` but you can do that with the `on_reaction_add` event function in both `async` and `rewrite`

Comment: Is i supposed to be the server id?
Also I would very much appreciate if you told me if I can find a message using a part of it's text without on_message or the message id? Basically what I need after a reaction is added to a post (that has a username associated with it e.g. 'BlacktarSalmon#3635 has come to event) it reacts to a different post that was posted earlier (e.g. 'BlacktarSalmon#3635 has attented those events')?
It's because I'm using another channel for data storage EDIT: just realised where i need the server id, but my second question still stands

Comment: @JonSalman, I've edited the answer, please let me know if that's what you meant

Comment: the first one is a no, but the last one,im pretty sure is what i needed. Does the last one just scan messages from the specified channel or just the ones that are in its cache?

Comment: It scans the amount of message s you tell it to within the channel specified  via `limit=22` parameter inside the `logs_from` function

Comment: does it scan from newest to oldest? e.g. the newest one will be 1 or the other way around?

Comment: From newest to oldest, can be changed through `reverse=True` default is set to `False` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from) is the documentation

Comment: You're a lifesaver. God bless